# Errors with defining global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I'm getting errors while declaring a global variable. I defined a global variable inside a definition.

```
import os
import time as t
s = t.time()
import numpy as np
#print(os.getcwd())
#print(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
chDir = os.chdir("/storage/emulated/0/OS-TEST-FOLDER")
print(chDir)
#print(dir(os))
file = open("Times.txt",'w')
tann = []


def tanns():
    while True:
        epochs = int(input("Enter how many epochs please >>> "))
        
        
        for i in range(epochs):
            aa = np.tan(i)
            print(f'Writing Tan{i} in Process')
            aaa = f'tan {i} degree = {aa}'
        #   t.sleep(0.01)
            tann.append(aaa)
        #with open(file) as f:
        file.write(str(tann))
        #print(file)
            
        f = t.time()
        dur = f - s
        print(f'Finished writing {epochs} tan')
        print(f"The Program Finished in {dur} seconds ")
        
        global choice = str(input("Do you want to continue running the Program >>> "))
        
        if choice == "n":
            break
        
if choice == 'y':
    tanns()
```

This was the error I got when I ran this code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 34
    global choice = str(input("Do you want to continue running the Program >>> "))
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[Program finished]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour]. What's your question? You can [edit] to clarify. If you're looking for help with fixing it, the error points to the problem, so what are you confused about? Try reading [the documentation for the `global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global), though it might be too dense for a beginner. It would also help to provide a [mre], i.e. less code.

Comment: Try comparing your code with [this example using `global`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423596/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

You must declare the global variable before assigning a value to it.

change `global c = ...` to

```
global c
c = ...
```